# Is okay to create indexes on a table while insertion

Tags: oracle, insert, indexing

Is it okay to create an index on a table while , lets say when are there some tasks which creates some new rows into the table at the same time?? Would there be any locking issues???

EX:  FEEDBACK TABLE --> creating an index on (Name, feedbackrule) while there are any inserts happening simultaneously , is this BAD?? if so what.

I'm assuming, Oracle will just not use this index when the inserts are happening, later this will be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, creating an index requires locking the table, so all the DML operations would block; and if there are active transactions on the table when you initiate the index creation, you'd likely get the error "ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired".

If the table is small, this may not be much of an issue - transactions would just be blocked for a few moments.  But if it is very large it would be a bad idea to try creating an index while the table is in use.

However, if you using Enterprise Edition, you can add the `ONLINE` keyword to your `CREATE INDEX` statement, which will allow transactions to proceed against the table while the index is building.  It may still cause slower performance.